# Как найти скользящее среднее

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

```python
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller
%matplotlib inline

df = pd.read_csv('FTX Token Historical Data - Investing.com.csv')
df.Date = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.Date)
df.Price.plot()
```

Как найти среднее скользящее? [Ссылка на файл](https://www.investing.com/crypto/ftx-token/historical-data).

Comment: а что именно у вас не получилось? и зачем столько ненужных импортов для такой задачи?

Comment: `rolling` для этого есть https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html

Comment: спасибо rolling работает, но я сделал через цикл

Comment: @Nesiro очень плохо, что через цикл.

Comment: Учитесь сразу делать правильно, когда у вас будут реально большие данные цикл уже не справиться.

Comment: @strawdog я просто не смог понять какие значения в rolling нужно засунуть, как задать размер окна?

Comment: @Nesiro Вы мою ссылку открывали? Первый же параметр window - это размер окна